# App declined in App Store review for purchases not working, but they work in the sandbox on a physical device and over TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit

So my app has both consumable IAPs and non-consumable IAPs integrated and working properly on a physical device on my end, as well friends that have tested on TestFlight and made fake purchases but it got denied in the app submission review for:

**Next Steps**

**When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.**

My purchase manager looks like this:

```
import StoreKit

class PurchaseManager: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver,SKPaymentQueueDelegate {
    var delegate: PurchaseProtocol?
    
    var itemNumber = 0
    
    static let shared = PurchaseManager()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }
    
    func buyInAppPurchase(productID: String) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            // can make payments
            let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
            paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
        }else {
            //cant make payments
            
        }
    }
    
    func restorePurchases() {
        print("restore purchases called in purchase brain")
        delegate?.showSpinner()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
    
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        delegate?.hideSpinner()
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        print("restore failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
                
            case .purchased:
                print("transaction success")
                delegate?.hideSpinner()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                
                delegate?.sendInfo(itemNum: self.itemNumber)
                self.itemNumber = 0
                
                print("purchased: \(transactions)")
            case .failed:
                delegate?.hideSpinner()
                print("transaction failed")
                if let error = transaction.error {
                    print("Transaction failed due to error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                self.itemNumber = 0
                print("failed: \(transactions)")

            case .restored:
                print("transaction restored")
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                delegate?.hideSpinner()
                print("restored: \(transactions)")
            case .deferred:
                print("transaction deferred") 
                print("deferred: \(transactions)")
            case .purchasing:
                print("transaction purchasing")
                delegate?.showSpinner()
                print("purchasing: \(transactions)")
            @unknown default:
                print("transaction defaulted")
                self.itemNumber = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what to really do from here, and all the videos I've watched don't really have anything different from what I have, unless I'm missing something. Anyone know what I need to do with the receipt validation and why?

Comment: It might help to integrate a platform like Sentry.io so that you can get some logs as to what is happening. One issue I can see with your logic is that you should ensure that the purchase has been persisted before calling `finishTransaction`, but this won't be the reason for your rejection.

Comment: You haven’t shown anything about receipt verification. How are you verifying it?

Comment: I wasn’t aware I needed receipt validation. The tutorials I followed never mentioned validating receipts when implementing IAPs.